# Setting up a three way serial port from a single existing port

Tags: linux, serial, socat

I currently have a device that has a serial port, and on boot this serial port is bound to ttyS1. There is a process on the device (that I have little control over) that takes control of this port so you can talk to it through a serial terminal.

I want to be able to interact with this serial port through software running on the device though. The current method that I am using to do this is to basically hijack ttyS1 immediately after bootup and create a virtual serial port in it's place and then my software sits on the other end. If I do that, then the serial port is no longer accessible through the physical port though. Is there a way of doing this without losing access through the physical port?

[I've attached a photo to try and illustrate what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUXUr.png)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43211/write-data-to-both-a-file-and-a-serial-port-can-i-use-tee  might be give you a start

Answer (score 0):

you should definitely read this -

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-4.html